# QVector.push_back error

Tags: c++, qt

error in

```
QVector<LibraryRecord> Library;
Library.push_back(LibraryRecord(DateOfIssue, ReturnDate, FIO,tTekct,FName,TText));
```

error message:

```
 no matching function for call to ‘LibraryRecord::LibraryRecord()’
```

why? Constructor present

```
//constructor
LibraryRecord::LibraryRecord(QString pDateOfIssue,
                             QString pReturnDate,
                             QString FIO,
                             QString tTekct,
                             QString fName,
                                 QString TTextt)
{..}
```

Can you tell me how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unlike the C++ Standard Library containers (e.g. `std::vector`), the Qt containers require that the value type be default constructible.

That is, your type `LibraryRecord` must also have a default constructor (the constructor that you show, which requires arguments, is not a default constructor).

Comment: However, `QList` does not have this requirement, so I've wound up using it in some spots where I'd have preferred to use `QStack` or `QVector` but needed to support non-default-constructible types.

Answer (score 1):

Your class must be [assignable](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/containers.html#assignable-data-type). It is probably not.